# Is it possible to install Windows Debugging Tools via Powershell?

Tags: windows, iis, powershell, .net, debugging

I've installed LeanSentry on one of my web servers to try and diagnose some performance issues I've been having.  I need to install Windows Debugging Tools (from the Windows SDK) to get some memory diagnostics back from my app hosted in IIS.

The main issue is that I don't have remote desktop access to the server, I just have remote Powershell access, so I'm looking a way to do it via command line.  I can't seem to find any instructions online, not sure if I'm looking in the wrong places?

Comment: Why install it? All you need to do is copy the folder with the binaries.

Comment: Really? didn't even think of that, doh! Thanks